# How is negative mass related to string theory according to Eric Weinstein?

Tags: general-relativity, mass, string-theory, history

Eric Weinstein suggest in his [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O76fjTNGbtI) that string theory comes from [Hermann Bondi's famous paper related to negative mass](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.29.423) in 1957 Chapel Hill Conference and that gravitoelectromagnetism and string theory came from it.

What is the role of negative mass in string theory?

Comment: *according to Eric Weinstein* Bah. Please note that [Eric Weinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Weinstein) has written that he “is not a physicist” (despite his education as one) but rather an “entertainer”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is not alleging that string theory somehow originates from Bondi's analysis. His main claim (supported by an academic [here](https://royalsoc.org.au/images/pdf/journal/154-2-Rickles.pdf)) is that the first institutional support for research into quantum gravity came about, because the sponsors were hoping for technological applications of gravitational theory, such as antigravity. String theory came about much later, and originated outside the "mainstream" of quantum gravity research (in particle physics), but happened to yield a model of quantum gravity.

Bondi's paper is a *classical* analysis of negative mass, that yields odd solutions in which a negative mass chases a positive mass off to infinity, which might be inspiring if you are looking to create a warp drive. There have since been many other formal solutions to the equations of general relativity which look like this - the best known is the "Alcubierre drive" - but they all require negative masses, negative energies, and so on.

In the video you link, Eric proposes an iconoclastic framing in which kitschy antigravity research favored by ufologists, and quantum gravity research carried out by Feynman, Witten, etc., are paired together as lowbrow and highbrow versions of the same thing. I suppose the argument is that antigravity kitsch is pitched to ufologists, and quantum gravity research is pitched to science funding agencies, and what they have in common is no experimental evidence.

I may be missing certain nuances of what he thinks the similarities or connections are. But the message is clear, he is asking us to think of quantum gravity as a mistaken research program with disreputable origins.

One of the problems with this is that it is entirely natural to expect gravity to be quantized. All the other fundamental fields are quantized, why wouldn't gravity be quantized too? But owing to the weakness of gravity compared to other forces, it would be incredibly difficult to find any detectable imprint of its quantized nature. The individual graviton is just too weak, any detectable gravitational influence would consist of enormous numbers of gravitons that are indistinguishable from a purely classical gravitational wave.

(A small number of people have tried to find detectable signs of quantum gravity or the lack thereof - Jonathan Oppenheim's recently publicized work is an example of this - but a lot of those experiments test unorthodox versions of quantum gravity. Orthodox quantum gravity, in the sense of what you get if you quantize general relativity, simply doesn't give rise to detectable effects.)

So there was a highly theoretical trend of research on quantum gravity for a few decades. Later string theory took over, but it did not arise from within the 1957 program anyway! It was a model that developed within particle physics, intended to model subnuclear particles, which turned out to also contain states with the properties of a graviton.

String theory has become the target of iconoclastic attacks especially since supersymmetry didn't show up at the LHC. The average critic says it's a big theoretical daydream disconnected from experimental reality. The average critic probably doesn't understand how mathematically well-connected string theory is to the previous theories that have been confirmed - e.g. it contains all the types of particle that have been observed, along with the expected graviton - and probably what string theorists need to do, is to devise new kinds of models within string theory that reflect the post-Higgs reality. In any case, string theory is so much a sui generis phenomenon, that it seems hard to consider it an outgrowth of the hypothesis of quantum gravity (which itself has much better motivations than just the hope of antigravity!).

A few more comments... There may after all be signs of quantum gravity that we already know about. The mass of the Higgs boson was predicted by an unorthodox quantum gravity framework, asymptotic safety, three years before. Perhaps the "dark matter" (that also hasn't been observed directly, but which at least has ample empirical motivation) is actually some kind of gravitational quanta. There are a lot of things to explain, and a lot of ideas with which to explain them.

Finally I'll also add that I think Eric Weinstein's own theory has a lot more going for it than most physicists believe! It is not a theory presently capable of making quantitative predictions, it is more a "what-if" proposal - what if various field-theoretic objects can fit together in a novel way - and I think it's a bit of an intellectual failure that the relevant experts haven't tried harder to make it work, or otherwise incorporated the concept into their discourse. But like I said, there are a lot of ideas out there, and the people most capable of working on Eric's theory, probably prefer to pursue their own ideas.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the estimation of the Higgs mass through asymptotic safety?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0208 is the paper

Comment: (1) Just adding to what you said... It's the fault of the rhetoric of (some) string theorists that anyone thinks the LHC has something to do with string theory... there's no stringy reason to think that supersymmetry is broken at experimentally accessible scales. The arguments that the LHC should see new physics beyond the Higgs are due to the hierarchy problem, but that issue is independent of string theory. (2) There is a supposed rebuttal of Weinstein's theory [here](https://timothynguyen.files.wordpress.com/2021/02/geometric_unity.pdf), although I haven't gone through it in detail.

Comment: @Andrew Regarding (2), that paper raises valid issues, but there are ways forward. Unfortunately Eric Weinstein decided to respond in his "critic of the establishment" persona rather than his physicist persona, and just denounced them as ill-intentioned hooligans of orthodoxy, rather than respond to their actual arguments.